# sed/awk file data manipulation

Tags: ubuntu, awk, command-line, sed, regular-expression

I have many text files prepended with digits like this:

```
12 some text here
some text here
some text here
```

Or sometimes like this:

```
123 text here

some more not-so-interesting text here

some text here

even more not-so-interesting text here
```

And I need them to appear like so:

```
12

some text here
some text here
some text here
```

Is this possible using sed or awk or some command line tool? I just need the digits to be on a new line, isolated from the other text on the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remember the number and replace the space after it with a newline:

```
sed 's/^\([0-9][0-9]*\) /\1\n/'
```

If your sed supports it, you can use an extended regex to improve readability:

```
sed -E 's/^([0-9]+) /\1\n/'
```

- `[0-9]` matches a digit
- `*` means "zero or more times"
- `+` means "at least once"
- `\(...\)` or `(...)` create a "capture group", the first capture group can be referenced as `\1`, etc.
- `\n` represents a newline